# Difference between CALL, CALLCODE and DELEGATECALL

Tags: contract-design, contract-invocation, evm, delegatecall, callcode

CALL and CALLCODE take the same number of operands (in the execution stack). For the exception flag being pushed on top of the stack: 0 means exception, 1 means successful execution. CALL is easy to understand, but I could not digest the subtle difference between CALL & CALLCODE. It is stated in the yellow paper that for

> CALLCODE: This means that the recipient is
>   in fact the same account as at present, **simply that the code is
>   overwritten.**

What does it mean by the code *is overwritten*? Does that mean I can ask the contract to execute some external code? It would be helpful if anyone can provide me an example to differentiate between the two.

EDIT: DELEGATECALL was added in Homestead what is the difference?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

**`DELEGATECALL` basically says that I'm a contract and I'm allowing (delegating) *you* to do whatever you want to *my* storage**.  `DELEGATECALL` is a security risk for the sending contract which needs to trust that the receiving contract will treat the storage well.

`DELEGATECALL` was a new opcode that was a bug fix for `CALLCODE` which did not preserve `msg.sender` and `msg.value`.  If Alice invokes Bob who does `DELEGATECALL` to Charlie, the `msg.sender` in the `DELEGATECALL` is Alice (whereas if `CALLCODE` was used the `msg.sender` would be Bob).

### Details

When D does CALL on E, the code runs in the context of E: the storage of E is used.

When D does CALLCODE on E, the code runs in the context of D.  So imagine that the code of E is in D.  Whenever the code writes to storage, it writes to the storage of account D, instead of E.

```
contract D {
  uint public n;
  address public sender;

  function callSetN(address _e, uint _n) {
    _e.call(bytes4(sha3("setN(uint256)")), _n); // E's storage is set, D is not modified 
  }

  function callcodeSetN(address _e, uint _n) {
    _e.callcode(bytes4(sha3("setN(uint256)")), _n); // D's storage is set, E is not modified 
  }
  
  function delegatecallSetN(address _e, uint _n) {
    _e.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("setN(uint256)")), _n); // D's storage is set, E is not modified 
  }
}

contract E {
  uint public n;
  address public sender;

  function setN(uint _n) {
    n = _n;
    sender = msg.sender;
    // msg.sender is D if invoked by D's callcodeSetN. None of E's storage is updated
    // msg.sender is C if invoked by C.foo(). None of E's storage is updated

    // the value of "this" is D, when invoked by either D's callcodeSetN or C.foo()
  }
}

contract C {
    function foo(D _d, E _e, uint _n) {
        _d.delegatecallSetN(_e, _n);
    }
}
```

When **D does CALLCODE on E, `msg.sender` inside E is D** as commented in the code above.

When an account C invokes D, and **D does [DELEGATECALL](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-7.md) on E, `msg.sender` inside E is C**.  That is, E has the same `msg.sender` and `msg.value` as D.

***An important note***: in order for the DELEGATECALL to function properly, the storage layouts of the caller and the callee contracts (D and E, respectively, in our example above) needs to be compatible. If it is not, the DELEGATECALL may lead to unexpected behavior and erros.

You can [quickly test above in Solidity Browser](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/how-to-quickly-test-a-solidity-function).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is semantic is strange though. For example, I will never deposit my money to any contract which has such callcode operator. What can prevent someone from executing `(send money out of the contract to some different address)` in the callcode?

Comment: Maybe worth posting as another question to get other perspectives, but usually both contracts D and E would be written by same person, and you would probably only deposit money to a contract D that you trusted.  You're right, any contract D that does CALLCODE of another contract E must be careful of what E does, and anyone using D should also be cautious.

Comment: Can you also explain DELEGATECALL?

Comment: @PawełBylica Added DELEGATECALL and hope it's still clear.

Comment: would `this` be the same in the two contexts, similar to `msg.sender` and `msg.value`?

Comment: @TravisJacobs Yes.  Added a line to the answer (and tested it).

Comment: @eth `When D does CALLCODE on E, the code runs in the context of D. So imagine that the code of E is in D. Whenever the code writes to storage, it writes to the storage of account D, instead of E.` And in that case, which Ether balance is used, the balance of E or the Balance of D ?

Comment: @user2284570 `this.balance` would be D's balance. See code comment *the value of "this" is D, when invoked by either D's callcodeSetN or C.foo()*.

Comment: @eth including when E is sending some part of the balance ? Or is just the amount being returned like CODESIZE from E would return CODESIZE of D (which means E balance would be used for sending)

Answer (score 8):

Showing the difference between the call, callcode and the delegatecall we can consider the example of the following code :

Contracts can interact in three ways

1. Call : By directly calling from a contract through a function which will not set the caller's value but sets the callee's value. And sender in this will be the caller only
2. CallCode : When called through CallCode caller calls the function of the callee and sents its own value (or alter its own value with the called parameters ) but no changes are reflected to the callee's storage. Here also sender is the Caller itself.
3. DelegateCall : When a third contract calls a delegate call to some function in callee on behalf of the caller and storage changes are made in the caller's value and nothing is reflected in callee's storage .

   > Here the sender is no more the caller but the third contract Call Helper

pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

```
contract Caller {
uint public value;
address public sender;

function callSetValue(address _callee, uint _value) {
    _callee.call(bytes4(sha3("setValue(uint256)")), _value); // Callee's storage is set as given , Caller's is not modified 
}

function callcodeSetValue(address _callee, uint _value) {
    _callee.callcode(bytes4(sha3("setValue(uint256)")), _value); // Caller's storage is set, Calee is not modified 
}

function delegatecallSetValue(address _callee, uint _value) {
    _callee.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("setValue(uint256)")), _value); // Caller's storage is set, Callee is not modified 
}
}

contract Callee {
uint public value;
address public sender;

function setValue(uint _value) {
    value = _value;
    sender = msg.sender;
    // msg.sender is Caller if invoked by Caller's callcodeSetValue. None of Callee's storage is updated
    // msg.sender is OnlyCaller if invoked by onlyCaller.justCall(). None of Callee's storage is updated

    // the value of "this" is Caller, when invoked by either Caller's callcodeSetValue or CallHelper.justCall()
}
}

contract CallHelper {
    function justCall(Caller _caller, Callee _callee, uint _value) {
        _caller.delegatecallSetValue(_callee, _value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An update to @eth's example for solidity v6:

- function definitions must be `public`
- `keccak256` in place of `sha3`
- call arguments use `abi.encode()`
- `address()` to get contract address

  ```
  pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
  contract D {
     uint public n;
     address public sender;

     function callSetN(address _e, uint _n) public {
       _e.call(abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256("setN(uint256)")), _n)); // E's storage is set, D is not modified 
     }

     /*
     callcode is depreciated
     function callcodeSetN(address _e, uint _n) public {
       _e.callcode(abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256("setN(uint256)")), _n)); // D's storage is set, E is not modified 
     }
     */

     function delegatecallSetN(address _e, uint _n) public {
       _e.delegatecall(abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256("setN(uint256)")), _n)); // D's storage is set, E is not modified 
     }
   }

   contract E {
     uint public n;
     address public sender;

     function setN(uint _n) public {
       n = _n;
       sender = msg.sender;
       // msg.sender is D if invoked by D's callcodeSetN. None of E's storage is updated
       // msg.sender is C if invoked by C.foo(). None of E's storage is updated

       // the value of "this" is D, when invoked by either D's callcodeSetN or C.foo()
     }
   }

   contract C {
       function foo(D _d, E _e, uint _n) public {
           _d.delegatecallSetN(address(_e), _n);
       }
   }
  ```

Answer (score 7):

`callcode` has been deprecated in favour of `delegatecall` as per version 0.8.4

Comment: Yeah, but it was actually removed back in version 0.5.0, which was the version where many things got removed from Solidity.

Comment: @abhi3700 Although callcode has been deprecated has a globally available function (method from the ‘address’ type), it is still possible to use it in inline assembly and Yul. See following link to Solidity docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/yul.html#evm-dialect

Answer (score 2):

As said previously `address.callcode()`has been deprecated and cannot be used directly after solidity 0.8.

[image]

**However I see that the callcode opcode is still available in the opcode list after merge fork !**

[image]

Does that mean that one could still use assembly to use callcode ?
Are there any uses to keeping it?

Comment: As other people already said, it is deprecated and delegatecall should be used now. However, older contracts might still use the opcode. In the entirety of November, exactly four callcode calls were made (so it is pretty much dead). One of them linked below: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8620d9412e7620ccd10dee3db10514daeaa3c3b7fd493c374ef7b86990bdead1#internal

Answer (score 1):

update @atomh33ls answer

- use abi.encodePacked

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;


contract E {
    uint256 public n;        
    address public sender;


    function setN(uint256 _n) public {
        n = _n;      
        sender = msg.sender;     
    } 
}


contract D{
    uint256 public n;
    address public sender;


    function callSetN(address _e,uint256 _n) public {
         _e.call(abi.encodePacked(bytes4(keccak256("setN(uint256)")),_n));  
         
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! I understand that you're a new user and can't leave comments, but this answer as you've written it is more of a comment. I would recommend rewriting it as a complete answer - reference atomh33ls answer, and say why you're rewriting it (to correct the use of `encode` instead of `encodePacked`). Cheers!

Comment: There's an specific abi for this type of cases `encodeWithSignature`.