# How can a proxy contract create another contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, assembly, proxy-contracts

A simple proxy contract looks like:

```
contract Proxy {
    function forward(address to, uint value, bytes data) {
        if (!to.call.value(value)(data)) {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Using `to` zero [like `forward(0, 0, data)`] doesn't work.  Can a proxy contract create an arbitrary contract?

Can this code be modified or what's the Solidity inline assembly to do the job?

Comment: you would use `CALL`, `DELEGATECALL` or `CALLCODE` as described [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/difference-between-call-callcode-and-delegatecall)

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. In addition, you probably didn't notice the OP is the same person who wrote the answer you linked, so I guess he is aware of the mechanics described over there.