# call wont work in order to update another contract's storage

Tags: contract-design, delegatecall, callcode

Storage(variable `n`) of E won't get updated when I use `call` from contract D.

```
addressOfE = "0x13fac93069c10e977204b9b64502439740cbe46a"; //Contract E's address that exist on my private chain.
```

`call` does not update E's storage:

```
D.callSetN(addressOfE, 100); //I have waited transaction to be deployed.
D.getN(); //returns 0;
E.getN(); //returns 0;
```

---

`delegatecall` seems working:

```
D.delcallCfunc(addressOfE, 101);  //I have waited transaction to be deployed.
D.getN(); //returns 101; 
E.getN(); //returns 0;
```

---

`callcode` seems working:

```
D.callcodeSetN(addressOfE, 102);  //I have waited transaction to be deployed.
D.getN(); //returns 102; 
E.getN(); //returns 0;
```

[Q] What should I do to update E's storage by calling contract D's function? Is it possible?

I have tried the exact same tutorial on the following guide: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3672/4575

```
contract D {
  uint public n;
  address public sender;
  function callSetN(address _e, uint _n) {
    _e.call(bytes4(sha3("setN(uint256)")), _n); // E's storage is set, D is not modified 
  }

  function callcodeSetN(address _e, uint _n) {
    _e.callcode(bytes4(sha3("setN(uint256)")), _n); // D's storage is set, E is not modified 
  }

  function delegatecallSetN(address _e, uint _n) {
    _e.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("setN(uint256)")), _n); // D's storage is set, E is not modified 
  }
  function getN() constant returns(uint){
      return n;
  }
  function getSender() constant returns(address){
       return sender;
   }
}

contract E {
  uint public n;
  address public sender;
  function setN(uint _n) {
    n = _n;
    sender = msg.sender;
    // msg.sender is D if invoked by D's callcodeSetN. None of E's storage is updated
    // msg.sender is C if invoked by C.foo(). None of E's storage is updated
  }
  function getN() constant returns(uint){
      return n;
  }
    function getSender() constant returns(address){
       return sender;
   }
}
```

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: You may just need to supply more gas. Try `_e.call.gas(5000)(bytes4(sha3("setN(uint256)")), _n)`

Comment: Yep it worked when I supply more gas. @Tjaden Hess