# how does library end up in contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

```
library C {
   function a() public returns (uint) {
      return 15;
   }
}

contract A { 
    
   function a() public returns (uint) {
      return C.a();
   }
  
}
```

This is the code I am using.  I am trying to figure out how library C ends up in contract A's bytecode.

**Question 1)** I use remix and I compile contract A. In the bytecode, I can see the following `__$de3f906ec3d3531c3d498f8b283d7f02e6$__`. It doesn't matter if I change library C's function a's name or if I change what it returns. In the bytecode, there's always the same `__$de3f906ec3d3531c3d498f8b283d7f02e6$__`. Of course, If I use the library's function 2 times, then I will meet that strange string 2 times in the bytecode. What is it ?

**Question 2)** The answer to the above question could be `it's a placeholder`, where in the end, it's library's address that ends up in there.  If that's correct, then how does remix link `library C` to `contract A` ? because both library and contract are in the same file, and when I want to deploy, I only deploy `contract A` (i don't deploy or link library at all). Any idea ? How do I get the library address in that matter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__$de3f906ec3d3531c3d498f8b283d7f02e6$__` is a placeholder for library address.

The deployment process of smart contracts look somewhat like this

- Library is compiled
- Library is deployed, gets an address
- Contract using library is compiled
- Contract is "linked" - all placeholders in the bytecode are replaced with the library address
- Contract is deployed

Comment: Also because library is just another contract, it has a state. [This has scary implications](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30128/explanation-of-parity-library-suicide)