# Solidity CALL and DELEGATECALL: messages and data format

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, calldata, delegatecall

I have some questions about Solidity `CALL` and `DELEGATECALL`. I have already read some related threads ([link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/difference-between-call-callcode-and-delegatecall)), but found no answers to my doubts.

1) Is there any difference in performing a `CALL` to a function in a Solidity contract by directly calling the function (e.g. `funct(arg1)` ), or by using `addressOfTheContract.call(bytes4(sha3("funct(uint256)")), _n)`?

2) Is there any difference in performing a `DELEGATECALL` to a library function by directly calling the function (e.g. `lib.funct(arg1)` ), or by using `addressOfTheLibraryContract.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("funct(uint256)")), _n)`? Let's assume that in both cases the library is imported with an `import` statement at the beginning of the contract.

3) Do both `CALL` and `DELEGATECALL` generate messages with the same format of a transaction (`nonce`, `to`, `value`, ...), except for the `gasPrice` and `gasLimit` fields?

4) Finally, do both `CALL` and `DELEGATECALL` take place **locally** on each node?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a difference iff you are calling a function within the contract (an "internal" call). Internal function calls are done by jumps and do not require an actual `call` opcode. The longer form is equivalent to `this.funct(arg1)`
2. No, this should be equivalent.
3. No, `CALL` and `DElEGATECALL` are EVM opcodes just like `SSTORE` or `MUL`. No transaction is generated, all that happens is that code gets run.
4. All execution that occurs in a mined transaction happens on every full node on the network. If you simulate the transaction locally, e.g. with a web3 `.call` (not to be confused with the solidity `.call`) then it is run only locally

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of the first two answers, so wait for some confirmation from others:

1. No, these should do the same thing.
2. No, these should do the same thing.
3. No, calls between contracts don't create transactions at all.
4. This depends. They run wherever the rest of the code is running. If you make a transaction, the code runs on all nodes. If you use `eth_call` to make a call to a view/pure function, that executes locally on just the node you're talking to. A `CALL` or `DELEGATECALL` that's part of the function execution runs in the same place.