# Call Type Explained

Tags: calldata

I have yet to come across a well explained definition of all the call types in one place. 
* One of call
* Callcode
* Delegatecall
* Staticcall

Would be very grateful if someone could explain the intricacies of the differences.

Comment: What definitions HAVE you come across? Please share those definitions and explain what is not clear to you about them.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/difference-between-call-callcode-and-delegatecall