# What is the value of "address(this)" when delegate calling?

Tags: solidity, delegatecall, proxy-contracts

Suppose that you have an upgradeable proxy "Foo" that calls an implementation contract "Bar" via DELEGATECALL.

In "Bar", there is a function that uses the Solidity syntax `address(this)` to retrieve the address of the current contract.

What is the "current" contract when the call is made via the upgradeable proxy "Foo"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Remember how DELEGATECALL works](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/difference-between-call-callcode-and-delegatecall):

> DELEGATECALL basically says that I'm a contract and I'm allowing (delegating) you to do whatever you want to my storage. DELEGATECALL is a security risk for the sending contract which needs to trust that the receiving contract will treat the storage well.

So the answer is that `address(this)` will return the address of the "Foo" proxy, not of the "Bar" implementation. This wouldn't be a "delegation" if the answer was otherwise, would it?