# What is the difference between the STATICCALL and CALL EVM opcodes?

Tags: evm, delegatecall, opcode, callcode, static-call

Besides the regular and very common `CALL`, the Ethereum Virtual Machine has the `STATICCALL` opcode. In which ways does it differ from the regular `CALL`?

Edit: This is not a duplicate because this question is about `STATICCALL`, that question is not!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between CALL, CALLCODE and DELEGATECALL](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/difference-between-call-callcode-and-delegatecall)

Comment: @Ismael No it does not, I'm asking about `STATICCALL`

Answer (score 12):

Additionally,

> Since byzantium staticcall can be used as well. This is basically the same as call, but will revert if the called function modifies the state in any way.

Answer (score 5):

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-214

> STATICCALL functions equivalently to a CALL, except it takes only 6
> arguments (the “value” argument is not included and taken to be zero),
> and calls the child with the STATIC flag set to true for the execution
> of the child. Once this call returns, the flag is reset to its value
> before the call.