# How does DELEGATECALL behave when calling other contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, delegatecall

I am trying to make a Parent-Contract which has a function which spends ERC-20 Tokens. I want to call this function from different Child-Contracts (which are deployed independently) using Delegatecall.
I tried following sample-code:

```
contract Parent {
    
    address reciever;
    MyERC20 token;
    
    constructor(address _token) public {
        reciever = msg.sender;
        token = MyERC20(_token);
    }
    
    function payReciever(uint256 amount) public {
        
        token.transfer(reciever, amount);
        
    }
    
}

contract Child {
    
    address child;
    
    constructor(address _child) public {
        child = _child;
    }
    
    function transfer(uint amount) public returns (bool) {
        
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = child.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("payReciever(uint256)", amount)
        );
        return success;
        
    }
    
}
```

So summarized, I want that payReciever() is called with the state of Child and then executes the transfer using Child as the sender.

Unfortunately, the delegatecall returns false and I can´t quite figure out why.

What is msg.sender in token.transfer()?
What could be the problem in the above Code?

Comment: "What is msg.sender in token.transfer()?" - it's the Parent instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between CALL, CALLCODE and DELEGATECALL](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/difference-between-call-callcode-and-delegatecall)

Comment: please be aware of the security risks of using delegatecall