# Solidity call() and delegateCall()

Tags: solidity

After reading this article about Solidity `call()` and `delegateCall()`: https://medium.com/coinmonks/delegatecall-calling-another-contract-function-in-solidity-b579f804178c

I have the following questions:

It mentions in the end (Wrap Up section):

> - If we know the ABI of the target function, we can directly use the target function signature
> - If we don’t know the ABI of the target function, we can use call(), or delegatecall(). But in the case of delegatecall(), we need to care
>   about the order of the field variable.

But if we look at the `call()` and `delegateCall()` for the Calculator contract example, we still needed the Calculator address and the function signature as well, as per the line of code below. So what is the difference then? `call()` and `delegateCall()` also need the ABI of the target function.

```
function addValuesWithDelegateCall(address calculator, uint256 a, uint256 b) public returns (uint256) {
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = calculator.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("add(uint256,uint256)", a, b));
        emit AddedValuesByDelegateCall(a, b, success);
        return abi.decode(result, (uint256));
    }
    
    function addValuesWithCall(address calculator, uint256 a, uint256 b) public returns (uint256) {
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = calculator.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("add(uint256,uint256)", a, b));
        emit AddedValuesByCall(a, b, success);
        return abi.decode(result, (uint256));
    }
```

It also mentions:

> In Ethereum function call can be expressed by bytecode as long as 4 +
> 32 * N bytes. And this bytecode consists of two parts

What does `N` represent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between CALL, CALLCODE and DELEGATECALL](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/difference-between-call-callcode-and-delegatecall)

Answer (score 2):

`N` represents the number of arguments that the function takes.

For a function: `add(uint256,uint256)`, N would be 2 and hence the function call would be 4 + 32*2 = 68 bytes long

The difference is that when contract A executes delegatecall to contract B, B's code is executed with contract A's storage, msg.sender and msg.value.

To give you a simpler example:

```
pragma solidity >0.8.0;

contract Receiver {
    string greeting = "Hello";
    
    event Greeting(string greeting);
    
    function greet() external  {
        emit Greeting(greeting);
    }
}

contract Sender {
    string greeting = "Hi";
    
    function delegatedGreeting(address _contract) external {
        (bool success,) = _contract.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("greet()")
        );
    }
    
    function callGreeting(address _contract) external {
        (bool success,) = _contract.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("greet()")
        );
    }
}
```

You can try this on Remix. Here are the event logs:

```
    Greeting event after call from Sender to Receiver.greet:
    {
        "event": "Greeting",
        "args": {
            "0": "Hello",
            "greeting": "Hello"
        }

    Greeting event after delegating call from Sender to Receiver.greet:
    {
        "event": "Greeting",
        "args": {
            "0": "Hi",
            "greeting": "Hi"
        }
    }
```