# Does `delegatecall` create a new stack frame?

Tags: solidity, delegatecall, yul

[It seems like it was introduced](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/difference-between-call-callcode-and-delegatecall) to replace `callcode` because `callcode` modified `msg.sender` and `msg.value`, and that breaks a lot of use cases.

If the msg fields aren't changed, that leads us to think a new stack frame is not created.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `delegatecall` creates a new stack frame.