# How to build a 3 contract structure with delegatecall

Tags: contract-development, delegatecall, msg.sender

I'm looking for help to build an intermediate contract using delegatecall. My challenge would be with 3 contracts.

I need contract A to be the owner of Contract B, and contract B to have a transferownership function to transfer to another address but to be only owner, the role of contract C will be as an intermediary, contract A must make a call to C and the C delegatecall to the B.

The function to be performed on B is onlyowner, so only A could do it, but it needs an intermediate contract.

I was trying with this test:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// ContratoA.sol
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./ContratoC.sol";  // Importe o ContratoC aqui

contract ContratoA {
    address public owner;
    address public contratoB;
    address public contratoC;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Somente o proprietario pode chamar esta funcao ESTOUNOCONTRATOA");
        _;
    }

    event ContratoBIncluido(address indexed contratoB);
    event ContratoCIncluido(address indexed contratoC);
    event OwnershipTransferAttempt(address indexed newOwner, bool success);

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function incluirContratoB(address _enderecoContratoB) public onlyOwner {
        contratoB = _enderecoContratoB;
        emit ContratoBIncluido(contratoB);
    }

    function incluirContratoC(address _enderecoContratoC) public onlyOwner {
        contratoC = _enderecoContratoC;
        emit ContratoCIncluido(contratoC);
    }

    // Função para chamar transferOwnershipContratoB no Contrato C
    function transferOwnershipContratoB(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        require(contratoC != address(0), "Endereco do Contrato C nao configurado");

        emit OwnershipTransferAttempt(newOwner, false);

        ContratoC contratoCInstance = ContratoC(contratoC);
        contratoCInstance.transferOwnershipContratoB(newOwner);

        emit OwnershipTransferAttempt(newOwner, true);
    }
}


// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ContratoB {
    address public owner;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Somente o proprietario pode chamar essa funcaoESTOUNOCONTRATOB");
        _;
    }

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);

        require(newOwner != address(0), "Endereco invalido");

        address previousOwner = owner;
        owner = newOwner;

        emit OwnershipTransferred(previousOwner, newOwner);
    }

    function getOwner() public view returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }
}


// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

// ContratoC.sol
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./ContratoB.sol";

contract ContratoC {
    address public contratoA;

    event BeforeDelegateCall(address newOwner);
    event AfterDelegateCall(bool success, bytes data);
    event DelegateCallData(bytes data); // Declaração do evento adicionada

    modifier onlyContratoA() {
        require(msg.sender == contratoA, "Somente o Contrato A pode chamar essa funcao CONTRATOC");
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        // ContratoA ainda não está definido ao criar ContratoC
    }

    function setContratoA(address _contratoA) public {
        require(_contratoA != address(0), "Endereco do Contrato A invalido");
        contratoA = _contratoA;
    }

    function transferOwnershipContratoB(address newOwner) public onlyContratoA {
        require(contratoA != address(0), "Endereco do Contrato A nao configurado");

        emit BeforeDelegateCall(newOwner);

        (bool success, bytes memory data) = contratoA.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("transferOwnership(address)", newOwner)
        );

        // Adiciona logs adicionais para depuração
        emit AfterDelegateCall(success, data);
        emit DelegateCallData(data);

        require(success, "Chamada para o Contrato A falhou");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `ContratoA` is owner of `ContratoB`, then only `ContratoA` can call `contractB.transferOwnership()`. There's no way for `ContratoC` to call `contractB.transferOwnership()`.

You can make that `ContratoA` delegatecalls some function in `ContratoC`. Then that function will execute as if it were `ContratoA`, and it may call `contractB.transferOwnership()`.

```
contract ContratoA {
    address public owner;
    address public contratoB;
    address public contratoC;

    // ...

    function foo(address newOnwer) public {
        contratoC.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("bar(address)", newOwner));
    }
}

// Since ContratoA delegatecalls ContratoC both have to be compatible
// e.g. same variables in the same order, etc.
contract ContratoC {
    address public owner;
    address public contratoB;
    address public contratoC;

    // ..

    function bar(address newOnwer) public {
        ContratoC(contractB).transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }
}
```

PD: I didn't have time to test so take the code as an idea. It is missing error checks.

Comment: So let's suppose that the Contract is already published and does not have the delegatecall nor has a specific call been foreseen to call the transferownership function in contract B, the delegatecall will not work right?

Do you believe there is any solution?

I have a real problem with this case I went through.

Comment: @LeandroLoures Unfortunately, in that conditions then only `ContractA` can call `ContractB.transferOwnership`. Check this answer that explains how delegatecall works https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/difference-between-call-callcode-and-delegatecall.