# Difference between "specific" and "generic" proxy functions and how/when to use them

Tags: solidity, proxy-contracts

Hello I am trying to build a proxy contract and I've seen two approaches:

1- "Specific" proxy function, where the proxy function can only call a specific function of the other contract.

Ex: (taken from this [post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/call-function-on-another-contract))

```
contract Proxy is mortal {

address watch_addr  = 0xEB1e2c19bd833b7f33F9bd0325B74802DF187935;
address user_addr   = msg.sender;

function register(string _text){
    Name name = Name(watch_addr);
    name.register(_text);
}}
```

2- "Generic" proxy function, where the function can be used to call any other function of any other contracts:

```
contract Proxy is Owned {
event Forwarded (
    address indexed destination,
    uint value,
    bytes data
);

function () payable{}

function forward(address destination, uint value, bytes data) onlyOwner {
    if (!destination.call.value(value)(data)) {
        throw;
    }
    Forwarded(destination, value, data);
}}
```

I have two questions:

1 - What are the advantages/disadvantages of the two techniques?

2 - How does one uses "Generic" proxy functions? I'm not sure how I construct the parameters value and data required to run the transaction. I'm also not sure if I need to fund the contract before (my guess is yes)

Answer (score 1):

> 1 - What are the advantages/disadvantages of the two techniques?

The advantage of the first is, that you don't have to build `bytes data` yourself, the disadvantage is that you have to change it every time for every new function at the destination.

> 2 - How does one uses "Generic" proxy functions? I'm not sure how I construct the parameters value and data required to run the transaction.

In web3, having the ABI, you can encode the function call. See https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-abi.html#encodefunctioncall

Alternatively, if you need to call some other code before delegating, you can wrap it like this (example without sending value):

```
contract TargetInterface {
    function(uint x) public;
}

contract Caller is TargetInterface {
    GenericProxy p;
    address target;

    function(uint x) public {
        // ..CODE BEFORE..
        p.forward(target, msg.data)
        // ..CODE AFTER..
    }
}

contract Target is TargetInterface {
    function(uint x) public {...}
}
```

Finally you can use the abi object in Solidity to craft your own message data: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/units-and-global-variables.html

> I'm also not sure if I need to fund the contract before (my guess is yes).

To forward the value, you have to send the value to the Proxy first or make `forward` payable.

Comment: How could we decode `msg.data` in `p.forward()` function call @ivicaa