# How to interact with any ERC721 contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-721

We can interact with a contract that we have a sample of. To make it clear, please see how `Proxy` contract interact with `Name` contract in [this response](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2831/96126).

In my scenario, I want to check if the `msg.sender` is the owner of an NFT. So, I'm trying to interact with any ERC721 contract using the same way instead direct contract call. Like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.5.0/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.5.0/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

contract Market {
    function putOnSale(address _nftContract, uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _price) public payable {
        address tokenOwner = ERC721(_nftContract).ownerOf(_tokenId); // ???
        require(tokenOwner == msg.sender, 'Only owner...');
        
        // Rest of the code...
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting this error when I call `putOnSale` method:

```
transact to Market.putOnSale errored: VM error: revert.

revert 
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

**Can't I interact with another ERC721 contract using this way?**

Note: I'm doing this all in Remix IDE JavaScript VM.

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Try to inject into Testnet and test it. I tried on Rinkeby testnet and it works!

Comment: @Kerry99 did you mean injected Web3? I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to send any Ether when you call `putOnSale`? If not, that's what flagging your error. You only want to declare a method `payable` if you intend on directly sending Ether (specifically, not any other ERC-20) to it.

Comment: Yes, I'm sending Ether on call. I tried to remove `payable` and call without Ether also. @JoeHabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what little you've provided, the only thing I can see is that you're using the contract where you should be using the interface. i.e. This line:

```
   address tokenOwner = ERC721(_nftContract).ownerOf(_tokenId); // ???
```

should be:

```
    address tokenOwner = IERC721(_nftContract).ownerOf(_tokenId)
```

If you're not coming from a language where you're used to working with pointers, the difference between these two likely is pretty confusing. In short, you use:

- The **interface** when you want to call out to an **already deployed contract** (`IERC721`).
- The **contract** when you want to deploy a **new contract** (`ERC721`).

What you have written now reads like you're trying to deploy a new `ERC721` contract, with `_nftContract` as the name, and then immediately ask for the owner of the given token. The problem here is that according to [OpenZepplin's ERC721 API docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721-ownerOf-uint256-), this method requires that the `tokenId` exists. Since you haven't minted any tokens at this point, this is going to revert the transaction.

If you're still new to Solidity and aren't entirely sure of these things, I recommend avoiding any initial temptation to reduce code down to one liners. You'll find that sometimes `VM error: revert` is all the more insight that you'll get from the EVM error message. If you have multiple function calls on line, this can be harder to think through.

Writing this as:

```
    IERC721 nft = IERC721(_nftContract);
    address tokenOwner = nft.ownerOf(_tokenId);
```

or when deploying new contracts, like this:

```
    ERC721 nft = new ERC721(_nftName, _nftSymbol);
    nft.mint(msg.sender, _tokenId);
```

can make it easier to know exactly where things are going wrong, especially since you might not know if the address coming through actually is an `ERC721`.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation and information, @Joe Habel! You saved me. I tested your suggestions and I found the solution. **But, the problem is not about using or not using the interface. In both cases, I can interact with the contract I want. But make sure that contract is in the same chain**, I mean, it must be in the `Rinkeby` for example as we're working in **Rinkeby**. :) I was trying to call a main-net contract, so there is no contract to interact with. I recognized it after I write the code in multiple lines.